# method that shows kernel content in Keras

Tags: python, keras, convolution

How can I see the content of each kernel (filter) that in used in convolution layer of Keras after training the model?

(For example, for a 2D convolution layer with 10 filters (3*3).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model is saved in `model`, you can access the kernels of the Nth layer like this:

```
kernels = model.layers[N].kernel
```

For a 2D convolution with 10 3x3 kernels, the shape would be [3, 3, x, 10], where x is the number of channels on the previous layer. You can visualize the contents with matplotlib for example.